# Configuring SQL Server 2012 instance to have multiple instance names

Tags: sql-server-2012

I just installed SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition and set up a new default instance. Is there a way to "forward" connections from the old .\sqlexpress to the new default instance? Or do I need to hunt down and change all connection strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to update the connection strings if you've specified instance names in it and the instance name is changing. In the future, you should use [SQL Server Aliases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2012/05/21/how-to-add-a-hostname-alias-for-a-sql-server-instance.aspx) for production applications.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't ever plan on the instance changing TBH. Guess I won't make that mistake again.

Comment: Eventually, it will always change if your application has enough longevity to make it to where your hardware or OS needs to be upgraded. Aliases help ease that.